# Is there a better way to use strip() on a list of strings? - python

Tags: python, string, list, iterator, strip

For now i've been trying to perform strip() on a list of strings and i did this:

```
i = 0
for j in alist:
    alist[i] = j.strip()
    i+=1
```

Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: Upvoting for random anonymous uncommented downvote. If there is something wrong with the question, it's utterly meaningless to downvote without telling the author what.

Comment: If you want to iterate using indices, do `for (i, value) in enumerate(alist)`

Comment: I've added a benchmark which compares some options described here.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be using `list` as a variable name since it's a type.  Regardless:

```
list = map(str.strip, list)
```

This will apply the function `str.strip` to every element in `list`, return a new list, and store the result back in `list`.

Comment: +1 that's the way. And if you want to alter the same list instance instead of binding the variable to a new one (say, not to break other references to this list), use the slice syntax like @kojiro said

Comment: An example where `map` is an excellent choice. (`itertools.imap` might or might not be better, of course, as for example when assigning to a slice).

Comment: @Kos In that case, an iterator-based solution would be even better (as it avoids creating a whole list which is then unreferenced and awaiting garbage collection).

Comment: no worries, memory shouldn't be a problem since i'm reading a file, searching a string and dumping it away once i've found the index of a string. =)

Comment: Instead of using map and storing the data in the list again, itertools.imap is better in case of python 2.x. In python 3.x map will return iter.

Answer (score 19):

You could use list comprehensions

```
stripped_list = [j.strip() for j in initial_list]
```

Comment: Do you think list comprehensions make code work faster?? or just smaller??

Comment: List comprehensions are very efficient for iterable object with simple rules. You may use maps and list comprehensions depending on the complexity. But yes, they do provide a quick and efficient implementation

Answer (score 11):

Some intriguing discussions on performance happened here, so let me provide a benchmark:

http://ideone.com/ldId8

```
noslice_map              : 0.0814900398254
slice_map                : 0.084676027298
noslice_comprehension    : 0.0927240848541
slice_comprehension      : 0.124806165695
iter_manual              : 0.133514881134
iter_enumerate           : 0.142778873444
iter_range               : 0.160353899002
```

So:

1. `map(str.strip, my_list)` is the fastest way, it's just a little bit faster than comperhensions.

   - Use `map` or `itertools.imap` if there's a single function that you want to apply (like str.split)
   - Use comprehensions if there's a more complicated expression
2. Manual iteration is the slowest way; a reasonable explanation is that it requires the interpreter to do more work and the efficient C runtime does less
3. Go ahead and assign the result like `my_list[:] = map...`, the slice notation introduces only a small overhead and is likely to spare you some bugs if there are multiple references to that list.

   - Know the difference between mutating a list and re-creating it.

Comment: Do you mean `my_list = map(str.strip, list[:])`?  'Cause the other way gives me a NameError.

Comment: I mean `my_list[:] = map(str.strip, my_list)`. See the code under the link.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean

```
a_list = [s.strip() for s in a_list]
```

Using a generator expression may be a better approach, like this:

```
stripped_list = (s.strip() for s in a_list)
```

offers the benefit of lazy evaluation, so the `strip` only runs when the given element, stripped, is needed.

If you need references to the list to remain intact outside the current scope, you might want to use list slice syntax.:

```
a_list[:] = [s.strip() for s in a_list]
```

For commenters interested in the speed of various approaches, it looks as if in CPython the generator-to-slice approach is the least efficient:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit as t
>>> t("""a[:]=(s.strip() for s in a)""", """a=[" %d " % s for s in range(10)]""")
4.35184121131897
>>> t("""a[:]=[s.strip() for s in a]""", """a=[" %d " % s for s in range(10)]""")
2.9129951000213623
>>> t("""a=[s.strip() for s in a]""", """a=[" %d " % s for s in range(10)]""")
2.47947096824646
```

Comment: Why say "supposedly slightly more efficient" instead of profiling and checking? And BTW `[:]` is useful because then it alters the same list, not re-assigns the variable to a new list.

Comment: It's *less* efficient because it has to copy N items instead of replacing the reference to the list. The only "advantage", which you may not need or want, is that the change is visible to anyone who has another reference to the original list object.

Comment: imho, that's unpythonic.

Comment: I've changed this to a generator expression, as it's vastly more appropriate.

Comment: @Marcin it might be a more appropriate *approach*, but it's an incorrect answer to the question asked. I edited the question to describe both options.

Comment: @kojiro If you are assigning to a slice, a generator is more appropriate. You have edited your question to eliminate slice assignment.

Comment: @Marcin how is it more appropriate? I've added timeits and it doesn't seem to be as efficient. (I'm not equating efficiency and appropriateness, but I genuinely don't know why it would be more appropriate in the absence of efficiency.)

Comment: @kojiro You'll likely see better efficiency for larger lists, as less memory allocation will occur; secondly in real usage it is likely to lead to better overall performance, as there will be less in the way of garbage collectible, but uncollected objects hanging around.

Comment: Also, it's generally nicer for everybody else if you don't copy the interpreter prompts

Comment: @Marcin if I don't copy the interpreter prompts, how can you tell the difference between a command and its output?

Comment: @kojiro I usually comment the output like so `# => `, but a simple comment will suffice.