# how to use strip in map function

Tags: python, python-3.x, map-function

I'd like to use map to get list of strings:

```
value = '1, 2, 3'

my_list = list(map(strip, value.split(',')))
```

but got:

```
NameError: name 'strip' is not defined
```

expected result: `my_list=['1','2','3']`

Comment: `map()` doesn't return a list. Do you mean `list(map(...))` perhaps?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182777/is-there-a-better-way-to-use-strip-on-a-list-of-strings-python

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, even if the underlying problem is the same: this question asks specifically about `map`, while the other question does not, and the accepted answer there uses list comprehension instead of `map`, an arguably inferior solution to the problem.

Comment: At best, this could be a duplicate of the question @DimitrisFasarakisHilliard mentioned  as related

Comment: `map(str.strip, "1, 2, 3".split(","))` 

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`strip` is still just a variable, not a reference to the `str.strip()` method on each of those strings.

You can use the unbound `str.strip` method here:

```
my_list = list(map(str.strip, value.split(',')))
```

which will work for any `str` instance:

```
>>> value = '1, 2, 3'
>>> list(map(str.strip, value.split(',')))
['1', '2', '3']
```

In case you want to call a method named in a string, and you have a variety of types that all happen to support that method (so the unbound method reference wouldn't work), you can use a [`operator.methodcaller()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller):

```
from operator import methodcaller

map(methodcaller('strip'), some_mixed_list)
```

However, instead of `map()`, I'd just use a list comprehension if you want to output a list object *anyway*:

```
[v.strip() for v in value.split(',')]
```

Comment: Perfect answer, first I use map to convert '1, 2, 3' into [1,2,3] list(map(int,value)), but than I changed mind and fixed on map. But list comprehension is more pythonish

Comment: @TomaszBrzezina: I think the `map` approach is as pythonic as the list comprehension. `map` is *meant* for this use case. It's also shorter and performs better as a bonus.

Comment: What if we want to strip something other than space? Like `_` How do we pass it ?

Comment: @Hayat `methodcaller()` also takes arguments: `methodcaller('strip', '_')`

Answer (score 7):

You can also use a `lambda` to achieve your purpose by using:

```
my_list = map(lambda x:x.strip(), value.split(","))
```

where each element in `value.split(",")` is passed to `lambda x:x.strip()` as parameter `x` and then the `strip()` method is invoked on it.